# offsetTop relative to body and div behaves in different ways

Tags: html, css

I want to ask about offsetTop property on these two examples.

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/ging2507/pen/gOLBMLJ
[2]: https://codepen.io/ging2507/pen/zYomMON
```

The first one print 158 = 102(child1) + 48(body border) + 8 (body margin)
The second print 107 = 102(child1) +5(child  margin)

Can anyone explain why the first offsetTop = distance from **outer border of element** to **outer border of body plus margin **,  but in the second = distance from **outer border of element** to **inner border of parent **

Update question for more clear:

- In the first example offsetParent of a child is **body**(because the parent is position: static). In definition, I found in W3scholl (The offsetTop property returns the top position (in pixels) relative to the top of the offsetParent element.)
- In the second example offsetParent of a child is **parent**

**I found the answer if offsetParent is the body, it gets distance from element to HTML element**

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Are you wondering why the difference is `offsetTop`?

Comment: Thank you for reply. What im wondering is how browser calculate the offsetTop, and why in these 2 examples, the calculation is difference( the first include margin and border but the second it does not ). I've read the specification and example in W3school.

Answer (score 1):

`offsetTop` is the distance of the **current** element relative to the `offsetParent` element.

In one of your examples, you set the **margin** and **border** for the `.child` and for the `.parent`. These rules directly affect value `offsetTop`. Here:

```
.parent {
    border: 10px solid red;
    ...
    margin: 8px;
}

.child {
    ...
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: In the first example offsetParent of child is body(because  parent is position: static).  In definition i found in W3scholl 
(The offsetTop property returns the top position (in pixels) relative to the top of the offsetParent element.) . If in 1st example your calculate base on parent, i think your caculation is wrong, right ?

Thats because why i wondering, why the calculation is difference.

Comment: @langa, This is also due to `position: relative` in the second example. You set `position: relative` for the parent, and for the `parent` relative, your `.child` builds a value of `offsetTop`. Try experimenting with this and you will see why the difference is.